# IDE for debugging scons

Tags: debugging, ide, swig, scons

I have a project which uses scons and swig. Which IDE I can use for debugging the code? I want to set breakpoints and use "step over", "continue", .... while watching variable.

Answer (score 4):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org/) (Eclipse plugin) worked well for me in the past. Actually, the `scons` command you run to perform your build is a Python script -- you can replace it by a similar script within your IDE and launch that for debugging.

Having said that -- 
actually I found the *debugging* approach not so helpful when working with our SCons based build system. The reason is that SCons uses an *declarative* approach; your SConstruct defines the "what" of your build, and when stepping with the debugger, mostly you just see how the *parsing* and *evaluation* of that kind of "internal DSL" is implemented in Python (which is surely an educational experience, but not helpful for solving problems with my build).

Thus, usually I solve my problems just with adding some print statements to look into this and that variable in the current construction environment while the build script is evaluated. The manpage of SCons has extensive documentation about the various variables you can access in that environment object and in the dependency nodes defined when you add targets.

Answer (score 1):

Any Python debugger should be fine. [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a good place to start if you want a full IDE.

Answer (score 0):

PyTools and Visual Studio 2010 work great for me, though I settle for PyCharm CE/Pro when I can't use VS+PyTools. All of the VS debugging facilities (for the version that you are running) will be available for debugging Python (which are a bit better than PyCharm's). (There are extra performance debugging facilities in Enterprise.)

PyTools also supports VS2012 and VS2013, in addition to VS2010.

**NOTE**: Plugins/Extensions/Addons appear to only be available in VS Pro and higher, not Express.

- PyTools home: http://pytools.codeplex.com
- Visual Studio (trials available):
  http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs To
  buy the latest Visual Studio, google "Buy Visual Studio" (as the link
  changes), you can also google for a specific version. Many are
  available on Amazon.
- PyCharm home: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

As an aside, if you (or others on your team) want to *also* debug Django, PyCharm Pro is definitely the best for that.